# Magento - Override the tablerate resource model

Tags: php, e-commerce, shopping-cart, magento-1.7

I have read through the various threads on here however i can still not get the following problem resolved. I am attempting to override a resource Model using the method below, however i am having no luck at all.

Magento Version: 1.7

I would like to rewrite the the **Mage_Shipping_Model_Resource_Carrier_Tablerate**  class found at:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Resource/Carrier/Tablerate
```

I have copied the file too:

```
app/code/local/me/Shipping/Model/Resource/Carrier/Tablerate.php
```

and renamed the class within the file to:

```
me_Shipping_Model_Resource_Carrier_Tablerate
```

I have created a file in app/etc/modules/me_Shipping.xml that contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <me_Shipping>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Shipping />
            </depends>
        </me_Shipping>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Finally i have create a config.xml in: **app/code/local/me/Shipping/etc/config.xml**

I have tried many variations in this file, my latest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <me_Shipping>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </me_Shipping>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <shipping>
                <rewrite>
                    <resource_carrier_tablerate>me_Shipping_Model_Resource_Carrier_Tablerate</resource_carrier_tablerate>
                </rewrite>
            </shipping>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: Yes tried that, also have a little script on the command line for trying to load a class through Magento.. It also shows the Resource Model isn't getting overridden.. Thanks for replying :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <shipping_resource>
        <rewrite>
            <carrier_tablerate>me_Shipping_Model_Resource_Carrier_Tablerate</carrier_tablerate>
        </rewrite>
    </shipping_resource>
```

This resolves the issue

Comment: i try to overridde "app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Model\Resource\Customer.php" with this xml:  "<models>
   <customer_resource>
    <rewrite>
     <customer>My_Company_Model_Resource_Customer</customer>
    </rewrite>
   </customer_resource>
  </models>" but i get "Mage registry key "_resource_singleton/customer/customer" already exists"