# Override Mage_Shipping_Model_Resource_Carrier_Tablerate

Tags: magento

I want to combine Magento's table rate shipping and tall-paul's category-based shipping techniques (http://www.tall-paul.co.uk/2013/09/15/category-based-shipping-in-magento/). I can obviously edit the core class Mage_Shipping_Model_Resource_Carrier_Tablerate getRate function but I'd prefer to do it through my own module. I don't want to change anything else in the core table rate mechanism. Is there an easy way of extending this class in my module and have core table rate collectRates call my version of getRate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try code described in following link. How to rewrite this class is described there.

[Magento - Override the tablerate resource model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673185/magento-override-the-tablerate-resource-model)

**OR**

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/%7Bpath:viewforum%7D/viewthread/290462/

Comment: Great, that pointed me at the right approach. In the end I extended Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate and now I have category based shipping but falling back to table rates above thresholds, all by country.